# Bind a particular model to view among various models depending upon some condition

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one view and two models, depending upon some condition I want to bind the appropriate model.

I am trying something like this

```
@if (ViewBag.msg == "true")
{
    @model ECIFormsApplication.Models.MVC.Entities.Form6Model
}
else
{     @model ECIFormsApplication.Models.MVC.Entities.Form6Submission.Form6SubmissionModel
}
```

No doubt I get error only one model statement is allowed, but is there any way of achieving this ?

Comment: Just do the conditional check in the controller and return the appropriate view.

Comment: I have only one view I don't want to maintain two different views, Even if i do conditional check in controller what @model statement I am supposed to write in view ?

Comment: That makes no sense - if its one view it can only bind to one model.

Comment: Yes I know one view can bind only one model, but I want to decide at runtime which model should be binded to the view.

Comment: Again, that makes no sense. If your view is binding to `Form6Model`, then it cannot bind to `Form6SubmissionModel` unless they contained identical properties - it which case what is the point of separate models.

Comment: The point is both models have identical fields but view will use subset of those fields (some fields will be hidden in one particular scenario) . But even if fields are hidden they have "required feild validation" and I dont know how can I suppress that, so I thought could create two models containing same fields but different validation rules.

Comment: One option is to create one view model and apply conditional validation attributes (e.g [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`), but even that's crazy - just use two views (and it can be made up of partial views for common code to avoid duplication)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on not creating a second view, my opinion is to use one model and focus on disabling required validation when desired conditions are met. Do not try dynamic model binding, it is a bad idea and very difficult to implement. It will also make future maintainance more difficult.

There are ways to disable validation conditionally.

- in server side, by setting validator Enabled property to false or ValidationGroup to ""
- in client side, by using ValidatorEnable Javascript function

You can check this out :https://www.codeproject.com/questions/427158/how-to-disable-required-field-validator-when-contr